# Yii :: Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, yii

I am using the below code in the accessRules() function to match the roles of the logged in user. The role is set during the authentication process using

```
 $this->setState('role', $record->role);
```

The code in the accessRules() function is:

```
    $role="";
    if(Yii::app()->user->getId()===null)
    {
            $role="guest";
    }
    else
    {
        $role=Yii::app()->user->role;
    }

   return array(
        array('allow', 'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
   );
```

This code is working fine on my local machine but when I upload it to the server it gives me **`Use of undefined constant guest - assumed 'guest'`** error.
What is the reason for this and how can I resolve this. Thanks!!!

Comment: It's likely a `'` or `"` that you missed on a variable value. The code you showed doesn't really look relevant to your question. Actually if you look at the stack trace you should see exactly at which line the error occurs.

Comment: It is giving error at Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

Comment: Look at the complete stack trace. The error must obviously occur at a line where you use `guest`. PHP usually tells you exactly in which file and at wich line the error occured. If it doesn't (which would be odd) maybe you can search your code base for this word.

Comment: actually the thing is this is working fine on my local machine, But it does not work on the server.

Comment: Search in files for _guest_ without quotes or dollar sign ($) - it seems that on your local machine php error display settings set to ignore Notices (like this message about undefinded constant), but on your production server settigs are more like to show everything. It is useful to check setting error_reporting on your local machine's php.ini to "sync" behaviour - http://php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$role="";
if(Yii::app()->user->getId()===null)
{
        $role="guest";
}
else
{
    $role=Yii::app()->user->role;
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
$role = "guest";
if(Yii::app()->user->id != null) {
    $role = Yii::app()->user->role;
}
```

Try and see if this solves the problem for you.

You can also do this:

```
$role = "guest";
if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    $role = Yii::app()->user->role;
}
```

However, it seems you might be using the variable `$role` elsewhere, you may want to see if those lines are causing the problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

Followed [this post](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/) and changed the authorization process and it worked. Still not able to figure out why this warning was shown.